# Reading facebook post in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5

So what I'm trying to do is read a friend's post from facebook (and then display it in MVC), but facebook's documentation is quite lacking and out-dated. Other 
websites' tutorials suffer from the same: articles even from 2014 are out-dated already. From what I understand, I have to register as a fb dev (done), register my app 
(done), get an app token (semi-done, I'm getting only User Access Token), then GET the url with HttpClient (here's where the real problems begin).
So, first of all - what is the url supposed to look like? So far as I managed to come up with this setting:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<profile_id>/feed?access_token=<user_access_token>/`

This is supposed to (to my knowledge at least), retrieve the latest post from the specified user, but all I get when I paste that into browser is:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

The 'feed' in the url above can also be replaced with 'posts', but I just don't get the difference between these two. After reading through some (out-dated) graph-api basics, I know that another query syntax should be correct and it can be tested in their graph api explorer, but once again, I don't really know how, cause their documentation is lacking (I keep getting errors no matter what I try). It is supposed to retrieve 5 user's latest posts, but when I try to debug it in their explorer, it says I need to include a token, but I have no idea how to. This is how it looks like: `me?fields=posts.limit(5)`
By the way, is there some quicker way of getting profile's id rather than googling a page that does it for you? I managed to find nothing, after reading through facebook's decumentation.
Another question is: how do I get the App Token instead of User Access Token? The first option is greyed out at all times.

Comment: The official documentation is not outdated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed And it tells you that you need the permission of the user who’s feed you want to read. You can not just willy-nilly read the feed of random users.

Comment: I probably should've been more precise: it's not out-dated on every page. Some documentation pages are well written, while others lack explicit information, links and sometimes, they're just plain out-dated and not working, as is the case with the graph api overview. For example, while 'feed' does indeed state clearly that you need user's permission, getting that information out of 'post' page is harder, especially for a fresh developer like myself. And neither of the pages link or state how can you get that permission from a user.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post is pretty clear on what permissions are needed as well. And as for how to ask for permissions – that’s covered here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link here has it all pretty much, explained very well: [Embedding facebook feeds using asp.net mvc](http://www.logicalfeed.com/embedding-facebook-feeds-using-asp-net-mvc)
In case it goes 404 at some point, here's the code:

```
public ActionResult GetMyFacebookPageFeeds()
{
 var NumberofFeeds = 3;
 string PageId = "YOUR_FACEBOOK_PAGE_NAME_HERE";
 string AccessToken = "PLACE_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE";
 FBPostsModel posts;
 string FeedRequestUrl = string.Concat("https://graph.facebook.com/" + PageId + "/posts?limit=", NumberofFeeds, "&access_token=", AccessToken);
 HttpWebRequest feedRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FeedRequestUrl);
 feedRequest.Method = "GET";
 feedRequest.Accept = "application/json";
 feedRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
 WebResponse feedResponse = (HttpWebResponse)feedRequest.GetResponse();
 using (feedResponse)
 {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(feedResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
       posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FBPostsModel>(reader.ReadToEnd()); 
    }
 }
 return View(posts);
}
```

As for the FBPostsModel, you can get that by pasting the full url (with what you want to retrieve and a valid access token) into a browser, copying the whole message/page you get as a result, creating new class (named FBPostsModel) and using Visual Studio option of pasting with JSON converting (available at Edit->Paste Special->Paste JSON as Classes).

And as for the empty data result when trying to access a random facebook profile - you need permission from that user for that. With your own access token you can query only your profile and fanpages.

Comment: How to display post on view, can you share your FBPostsModel and view code

Comment: I'm getting the following exception "System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'"